# Wrong autodetection of biblatex backend

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, auctex

I'm using the `biblatex` package with option `backend=bibtex`. However, AUCTeX `C-c C-c` suggests running `biber`. How can I have the backend detected correctly, or override this and configure AUCTeX to always run `bibtex`? (I actually already have the BibTeX command run a script that checks and runs either bibtex or biber as approriate.)

Comment: The best is to use Biber, of course.